# FPM initialization failed

Tags: nginx, php

php5-fpm is not running some of the time. After restarting the php5-fpm , Everything is working fine and after some time again getting the same(php5-fpm is not running) error.

[image]

**Error Log :-**

```
14-Jul-2014 14:10:00] WARNING: [pool www] child 26439 exited on signal 11 (SIGSEGV - core dumped) after 58.134897 seconds from start
[14-Jul-2014 14:10:00] NOTICE: [pool www] child 26476 started
[14-Jul-2014 14:12:25] WARNING: [pool www] child 26454 exited on signal 11 (SIGSEGV - core dumped) after 203.243227 seconds from start
[14-Jul-2014 14:12:25] NOTICE: [pool www] child 26605 started
[14-Jul-2014 14:18:01] NOTICE: Reloading in progress ...
[14-Jul-2014 14:18:01] NOTICE: reloading: execvp("/usr/sbin/php5-fpm", {"/usr/sbin/php5-fpm", "--fpm-config", "/etc/php5/fpm/php-fpm.conf"})
[14-Jul-2014 14:18:01] NOTICE: PHP message: PHP Warning:  Module 'apc' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[14-Jul-2014 14:18:01] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=7, "127.0.0.1:9000"
[14-Jul-2014 14:18:01] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=7, "127.0.0.1:9000"
[14-Jul-2014 14:18:01] ERROR: epoll: unable to initialize
[14-Jul-2014 14:18:01] ERROR: epoll: unable to initialize
[14-Jul-2014 14:18:01] ERROR: Unable to initialize the event module epoll
[14-Jul-2014 14:18:01] ERROR: Unable to initialize the event module epoll
[14-Jul-2014 14:18:01] ERROR: FPM initialization failed
[14-Jul-2014 14:18:01] ERROR: FPM initialization failed
```

Comment: First, there is an issue with your apc. Could it be you have two conf files which want to load the apc module? If so, remove one. Second: what linux are you using, epoll is in linux >= 2.5.44 according to https://github.com/mastrolinux/php-msyql-nginx-varnish-memcached/blob/master/php5/fpm/php-fpm.conf. Your issue seems to be in the epoll module and not directly in php-fpm

Comment: i have checked apc configurations,But not able to find out any duplicate file for the same . Here i am pasting below the  apc configuration details . extension=apc.so
apc.enabled = On
apc.optimization  = 0
apc.shm_segments = 1
apc.shm_size = 512M
apc.ttl = 7200
apc.user_ttl  = 7200
apc.gc_ttl=3600
apc.num_files_hint = 20000
apc.mmap_file_mask = /tmp/apc.XXXXXX
apc.enable_cli = 1
apc.cache_by_default  = 1
apc.max_file_size = 10M
apc.stat = 0

Comment: The notice 'Module 'apc' already loaded' means that APC has already been loaded, the config itself looks good. But you want to enable APC trough a different file as well.

Comment: yes i got it.I have mentioned extension=apc.so module on both file php.ini and apc.ini and i removed it from php.ini.

Comment: HI i am getting different warning message :  [14-Aug-2014 12:03:10] WARNING: [pool www] child 2213 exited on signal 11 (SIGSEGV - core dumped) after 66.357267 seconds from start
[14-Aug-2014 12:03:10] NOTICE: [pool www] child 2254 started
[14-Aug-2014 12:04:10] WARNING: [pool www] child 2258 exited on signal 11 (SIGSEGV - core dumped) after 47.415239 seconds from start
[14-Aug-2014 12:04:10] NOTICE: [pool www] child 2298 started